# if the system kernel doesn`t support cifs, how to copy file from the windows share folder to linux

Tags: linux, kernel, cifs

if the system kernel doesn`t support cifs, how to copy file from windows share folder to linux. Any method can copy the file from windows share folder without cifs or mount?

Answer (score 1):

Some possible options: webserver, ftp server, samba server, ntfs or fat floppy disk or usb drive, winscp.....

Answer (score 0):

Use smbclient (it's like a simple FTP client for SMB, part of the samba package)